# huge log generate in WordPress websites

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, error-logging

In the past days, some WordPress websites generate huge error_log in public_html! all websites have cPanel.
in all websites that have this problem, those error logs are the same content.

```
 PHP Warning:  next() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 291
 PHP Warning:  current() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 275
 PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 277
```

I really do not know why this problem?
Why suddenly the logs are bulky?

Comment: This would certainly have to be due to some recent change. If you haven't changed anything regarding the Wordpress installation, then there seems to be a good chance your hosting provider changed something.

Comment: Problem reason is Litespeed !!!
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39338

Answer (score 0):

It was happened to me 2 days ago. I searched too much about this and finally i found the solution. You can put below code in public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php after line 291 (your error code) directory:

while ( is_array( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) && false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

This error is too bad and can make 20MB text in a second. I hope that you can solve this.

Comment: Can you comment on what this code is doing and why? Just suggesting to add some piece of code without giving any reference nor explanation is a bit too vague...